# Is there a CodeIgniter equivalent ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, codeigniter

CodeIgniter is a great tool for speeding up development. Is there a CodeIgniter equivalent for ASP.NET? I am very new to ASP.NET 4 and C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) would be the closest thing.

Comment: Amazing. I will definitely take a look into MVC. I just got excited. Thanks

Comment: [StackOverflow is created using ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/see-you-at-pdc-2008/)

Comment: I was looking into that. My next project will be utilizing MVC 3, it seems that it can potentially make things much easier